# concurrent testing of login functionality with 50 users/threads is not working

Tags: testing, concurrency, jmeter

i have given the thread count = 50 
rampup period =0

for 48 threaads it is getting passed , for 2 threads there is no failure captured in the selenium log files.

I am expecting concurrent login of 50 users with 0 rampup period , i am not able to find out the exact reason of failure . please suggest the fixes to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check [jmeter.log](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) file for any suspicious entries
2. Add [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your test plan - it will allow you to inspect request and response details
3. 50 real browsers might be too high for a single machin

   - as per [WebDriver Sampler documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/#Thread-Group)

     > From experience, the number of browser (threads) that the reader creates should be limited by the following formula:
     >
     > ```
     > C = N + 1
     > ```
     >
     > where
     >
     > `C` = Number of Cores of the host running the test
     >   and `N` = Number of Browser (threads).
   - as per [Firefox 62.0 system requirements](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/62.0/system-requirements/)

     > 512MB of RAM / 2GB of RAM for the 64-bit version

   So you will need a machine with 51 cores and 100 GB of RAM in order to ensure there will no be JMeter-side bottleneck. If your machine hardware specifications are lower - you will have to go for [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Comment: I am using linux server for testing this application , where Hardware specification of the machine is 36 cores , 251gb memory , 64 bit version